# How to increase the RSA key length from 1024 to 2048 from an existing certificate?

Tags: websphere, websphere-liberty

Can you help us to determine how to increase the Key Length from 1024 to 2048 to the following certificate attached from NodeDefaultKeyStore?

Answer (score 0):

#### Change RSA Key bits. Choose your method:

Method 1:

````
Then, Go to SSL Certificate and key management > Manage FIPS > Convert Certificates 
Then, select Strict SHA256withRSA and select 2048 bits  on key size.
Click on Apply, save on Master Configuration
Then,
From the Adminconsole expand System Administration > click on nodes > Fully synchronized
Then,
go to SSL certificate and keymanagement > Keystores and certificates > Nodedefaultkeystore > personal certificate and click on "default" certificate and see if RSA Key is 2048 bits.```

####  or Method 2:

``` Run from Deployment Manager's bin folder: 
wsadmin.sh
The following  command update key size and algorithm:
$AdminTask convertCertForSecurityStandard {-fipsLevel FIPS140-2 -signatureAlgorithm SHA256withRSA -keySize 2048 }
The following command save the above configuration changes.
$AdminConfig save 
The above Command will update and replace all default certificate that comes in websphere application server  with a new 2048 bit  key size for example files key.p12 for cell and node, trust.p12, root-key.p12..etc ```
````